# How can I save a string in one Activity pass it to another Activity and then come back to first activity with that?

Tags: android, android-activity

In an activity I have 2 buttons that those get their text from database. I have a problem with them, at first I set first button text and then click other button and go to another activity to choose my text from database but when I come back to previous activity first button text is null.
I try it with Intent and pass it to another activity and then retrieve it but it was not helpful!

What is your opinion if you test it before?

best regards

```
        btnIncomeFrom= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDaryaftAz);
    btnIncomeFrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        startActivity(new Intent(NewIncomeActivity.this, IncomeListActivity.class));
        }
    });
    IncomeTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("ThirdLevelIncome");
    btnIncomeFrom.setText(IncomeTitle);

    btnSettleTo= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVarizBe);
    btnSettleTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(NewIncomeActivity.this, SettleToListActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra("IncomeTitle",IncomeTitle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    btnSettleTo.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ThirdLevelSettle"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion better way to achieve this is use startActivityForResult() method. For example:

```
final int JADID_ACTIVITY_RESCODE = 1;
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(DaryafteJadidActivity.this, IncomeListActivity.class),JADID_ACTIVITY_RESCODE);
    }
/* invoked when started activity returns */
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
         Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == JADID_ACTIVITY_RESCODE) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             String retrived_data = data.getStringExtra("STRING_NAME","");
         }
     }
 }
```

And in Activity, after you retrieve data you can do:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("STRING_NAME",retrived_value);
setResult(RESULT_OK,resultIntent );
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem just with one condition:

```
        if(getIntent().getIntExtra("temp",0)== 1)
    {
        btnIncomeFrom.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("FinalIncomeTitle"));
    }
    else
    {
        IncomeTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("ThirdLevelIncome");
        btnIncomeFrom.setText(IncomeTitle);
    }

        btnSettleTo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(NewIncomeActivity.this, SettleToListActivity.class);                
            intent.putExtra("IncomeTitle",IncomeTitle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I passed temp with value 1 and FinalIncomeTitle that I passed to second activity when I want to come back to previous activity

```
                    intent.putExtra("FinalIncomeTitle",getIntent().getStringExtra("IncomeTitle"));
                intent.putExtra("temp",1);
```